# sails js, sample code as shown on the main page

Tags: javascript, socket.io, sails.js, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to experiment with sailsjs with a simple example as shown on their main page... but I get this

```
TypeError: socket.request is not a function
socket.request('/user', {}, function(users){ console.log(users); });
```

this is the peace of code

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');

    socket.on('connect', function (){
    socket.request('/user', {}, function(users){ console.log(users); });

    socket.on('message', function (message){
        console.log("Got message", message);
    });
});
```

please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this

```
socket.get('/user', {}, function(users){ console.log(users); });
```

socket object has no method 'request', it has get and post functions that will make request to corresponding route. In your case, if you are using blueprints, it will be a GET request for '/user' route that will be passed to 'find' method in your UserController.